# Is Interval indicated for representing numerical imprecision?

Tags: arithmetic, interval-arithmetic

#### Context

I am building a game that have numerical imprecisions. It has two stores that does not have accurate information about their inventory. This inaccuracy is represented by the imprecision percentage (e.g. 100±20% items). The inventory can assume negative values when there is demands and no items in the store's inventory. Further, the stores can send items between them. So, if there is less demand in one store, it can send more items to the other that has more demands.

I'm using Intervals to represent inaccurate numeric information in my game. There, I represent an inaccurate number as being any number in an interval. For example:
$100\pm20\%$ imprecision is represented by an interval $[80, 120]$.

The problem I am facing is with the Interval operations. When I **add** two intervals using the [Wikipedia Interval operations formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic) I am always able to maintain the same $20\%$ imprecision. For example with $100\pm20\% + 20\pm20\%$:

$[80,120] + [16,24] = [96,144] \text{ which is } 120\pm20\%$.

#### Problem

When I **subtract** two intervals using the following formula:

$[x_1,x_2]-[y_1,y_2] = [x_1-y_2, x_2-y_1]$

I get a different imprecision percentage.

$[80,120] - [16,24] = [56, 104] \text{ which is } 80\pm30\%$.

I noticed that the $80\pm20\%$ could be achieved by doing:

$[x_1,x_2]-[y_1,y_2] = [x_1-y_1, x_2-y_2]$

But I am not sure this would be mathematically correct.

#### Question

Am I using the correct operation for my problem? Should I be using something else other than intervals?

ps: All my intervals have the same imprecision. All $20\%$, or all $15\%$, or all $10\%$.

Comment: With your proposed alternative subtraction, you would get results like $[1, 2] - [3, 4] = [-2, -2]$ and $[1, 2] - [3, 5] = [-2, -3]$ which don't make sense. The operators in interval arithmetic lose precision. If your numbers are all positive, then addition preserves the percentage imprecision, but subtraction won't. If you allow negative numbers then addition doesn't preserve the percentage imprecision.

Comment: I don't see why it doesn't make sense, sorry. You are right about addition! If I add a positive interval to a negative interval, like $[-120,-80] + [16,24] = [-104,-56]$ it will modify the percentage imprecision. Now, I am lost. I really don't know what else to use to preserve the percentage imprecision.

Comment: Look at $[1, 2] - [3, 4] = [-2, -2]$: if that were correct, the result of adding two approximations would give a precise answer, which is absurd, while in my second example you get an impossible answer. You can't preserve the percentage imprecision using interval arithmetic unless all your numbers are positive and you only do addition. Note that percentage imprecision doesn't even mean anything for an interval like $[-1, 1]$. Perhaps you should say more about what you are actually trying to model in your game program.

Comment: I see! Thank you for the clarifications. About what I'm trying to model: I have two stores that does not have accurate information about their inventory. This inaccuracy is represented by the imprecision percentage (e.g. $100\pm20\%$). The inventory can assume negative values when there is demands and no items in the store's inventory. Further, the stores can send items between them. So, if there is less demand in one store, it can send more items to the other that has more demands. Should this be updated in the main question?

Comment: Please do add the extra information to the question. I think you may need a more precise model of how inaccuracies in the inventories arise, but I don't have any definite ideas. You might do better to ask your question on https://stackoverflow.com or https://cstheory.stackexchange.com where it might chime with somebody who has programmed a similar situation.

Comment: If all your intervals have the same imprecision, then I think you're better off just doing ordinary arithmetic with the midpoint, and applying the same imprecision with the result, if it's important to maintain that same imprecision.  That desire should be justified, however.

Comment: I see, thank you for the suggestion! I want to maintain the same imprecision because I tell the player that all numerical values will have a given imprecision percentage (i.e. 20%, 15% or 10%).
As a solution to my problem, I also thought on randomly selecting a number within each interval and doing ordinary arithmetic, and then applying the same imprecision. For example: $[80; 120] - [16; 24] \implies 96-19 = 77 \implies [61.6; 94.4]$